# Create shortcut to double click and select upto white space

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I have double click set to select the word between special characters in the gnome terminal. so for eg. consider `ls -ltr /user/root/folder`. If I double click on root then it will select only root. Triple clicking selects the entire line `ls -ltr /user/root/folder`:

1. Is there any way I can configure my system to select the word between whitespaces. so for eg. if I <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>double-click</kbd> on root then it should select `/user/root/folder`.
2. Is there any way to expand the selection. for eg. I double click and select root and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> selects user?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot configure a different behavior for Ctrl+doubleclick. You can, however, configure the behavior of doubleclick (without modifiers). Assuming GNOME Terminal version 3.16 or newer, see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730632#c33.
2. Shift+click expands the selection even after you've released the mouse. Another possibility is to "one and a half click" and then drag the mouse while the button is pressed down.

Comment: Are there any other terminal apps that allow for Ctrl + selection in the way  I mentioned. Even if I can triple click and select upto space while keeping double click behavior as it it will be an improvement.

Comment: I don't know (I don't think so, but maybe).